# When running shell command, python script only runs halfway before stopping

Tags: python, python-3.x, sh, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I created a python 3 script that takes user input for various numbers using easygui then calculates a time based off those numbers then creates a timer GUI from tkinter. That script runs just fine. However, I created an sh file to essentially make the script executable from the desktop of the Raspberry Pi 3 but it only runs the easygui part of the scrip (where the user inputs numbers). After the last number is input, the dialog box closes, as expected, but the timer window never opens.

My shell file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/pi/Desktop/Python/easygui-0.97/easygui
python potential.py
```

The rest of my code (the python script named "potential")

```
from partsperhour import hours_to_completion
from partsperhour import part_number
from partsperhour import cycle_time
from partsperhour import cavities
from partsperhour import work_order_amount


import math
hours_to_completion
dec,int_ = math.modf(hours_to_completion)
dec_=dec*60


str1=str(int(int_))
str2=":"
str3=str(int(dec_))
str4="00"
str5="0"



import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

def update_timeText():
    if (state):
        global timer
        timer[2] -= 1
        if (timer[2] <= 0 and timer[1] <=0):
             timer[2] = 59
             timer[1] -= 1
             timer[1] = 59
             timer[0] -= 1
        if (timer[2] <= 0 and timer[0] !=0 and timer[1] >0):
             timer[1] -= 1
             timer[2] = 59
        if (timer[2] <= 0 and timer[0] <=0 and timer[1] >0):
             timer[1] -= 1
             timer[2] = 59

        if (timer[1] <= 0 and timer[0] <= 0):
             timer[2] = 59    

        if (timer[0] !=0 and timer[1] != 0 and timer[2] == 0):
             timer[2] =59
             timer[1] -=1
             timer[2] -=1
        if (timer[0] ==0 and timer[1] ==0):
            timer[2] -=1








        timeString = pattern.format(timer[0], timer[1], timer[2])
        timeText.configure(text=timeString)
    root.after(1000, update_timeText)





def start():
    global state
    state = True

def pause():
    global state
    state = False

def reset():
    global timer
    timer = [int(int_), int(dec_), 0] #change values here
    timeText.configure(str1+str2+str5+str3+str2+str4) #change values here

def exist():
    root.destroy()

state = False



partstr=str(part_number)
partstr2="Hours until "
partstr3=" is finished"
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title(partstr2+partstr+partstr3)

timer = [int(int_), int(dec_), 0] #change values here for reset
pattern = '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}'

timeText = ttk.Label(root, text=str1+str2+str5+str3+str2+str4, font=
("Helvetica", 100)) #change values here
timeText.pack()

startButton = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start, height = 2, width 
= 10,bg = "green",font=('Helvetica MS',15),borderwidth = 4,relief=RIDGE)
startButton.pack(side="left")

pauseButton = tk.Button(root, text='Pause', command=pause, height = 2, width 
= 10,bg = "yellow",font=('Helvetica MS',15),borderwidth = 4,relief=RIDGE)
pauseButton.pack(side="left")

resetButton = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=reset, height = 2, width 
= 10,bg = "red",font=('Helvetica MS',15),borderwidth = 4,relief=RIDGE)
resetButton.pack(side="right")

quitButton = tk.Button(root, text='Exit', command=exist, height = 2, width = 
10,bg = "red",font=('Helvetica MS',15),borderwidth = 4,relief=RIDGE)
quitButton.pack(side="right")

w = Label(root, text="Part No. "+partstr, font = "Times 16 bold")
w.pack()


w2 = Label(root, text="Cycle Time: "+cycle_time+" sec", font = "Times 16 
bold")
w2.pack()


w3 = Label(root, text="Number of Cavities: "+cavities, font = "Times 16 
bold")
w3.pack()


w4 = Label(root, text="Total work order amount: "+work_order_amount, font = 
"Times 16 bold")
w4.pack()





update_timeText()
root.mainloop()
```

The partsperhour values it is pulling from can be seen here:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    numpad = NumPad(root)
    root.mainloop()




import easygui as eg

message1 = "Enter the part number"
part_number = eg.enterbox(message1, "Part Number",)  

message2 = "Enter the cycle time in seconds"
cycle_time = eg.enterbox(message2, "Cycle time",)

message3 = "Enter the number of cavities"
cavities = eg.enterbox(message3, "Cavities",) #User inputs the number of 
cavities

message4 = "Enter the total number required from Work Order"
work_order_amount = eg.enterbox(message4, "Work Order Amount",) #total 
number of parts needed

parts_per_hour = (3600/float(cycle_time))*int(cavities) #calculates how many 
parts will be produced in 1 hour

hours_to_completion = int(work_order_amount)/int(parts_per_hour) #calculates 
how many hours in total it will take

eg.msgbox(hours_to_completion, "Hours until complete")
```

So, essentially when I run the sh file it will perform all the actions from the partsperhour code but after that final box pops up and the user presses "OK" the timer does not show up at all. It is worth mentioning that if I were to run the module through IDLE 3 everything works as intended. It is only when I'm trying to use the shell file on the Desktop.

I'm not the most experienced with python but I feel as if I've gotten pretty far with this. If there is anyone that has some input that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: `hours_to_completion
dec,int_ = math.modf(hours_to_completion)` ?? missing assignment?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that isolates the specific problem (with a minimal dependency set so others can run it) rather than dumping all your code.